# PHP get Arabic Content from SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, arabic

How can I get Arabic content when I run `MSSQL_QUERY`?

It appears as `????`, I tried to do this:

```
$res = mssql_query($q);
$row = mssql_fetch_row($res)
echo iconv("unicode", "utf-8", $row[0])
```

but in this case it shows the value as Chinese letters as `潬穬`

any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: What encoding is your database connection in, what encoding is your database in, and what encoding is your output page in?

Comment: my database:
Sql server 2005: 
   DB collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS
   Server Collation: Arabic_CI_AS
My encoding in output page is: UTF8

Comment: and datattpe in sql server? I presume nchar or nvarchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Unicode data types. The Unicode data types are nchar, nvarchar, nvarchar(max), and ntext and you must precede all Unicode strings with a capital letter N.

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName) values(N'Arabic Text')
```

Comment: this was very long time away, and i have solved it in the same way you mentioned. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try installing the sqlsrv drivers found on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx. After following the instructions correctly, when connecting to sql server use :

```
$connArr = array(
    "Database"     => $dPconfig['dbname'],
    "UID"          => $dPconfig['dbuser'],
    "PWD"          => $dPconfig['dbpass'],
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($dPconfig['dbhost'], $connArr) or die("cannot connect");
```

it should work just fine 
Also see help docs of sqsrv drivers for other encodings.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try sending this to database before you select the arabic text:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

For example, when using PDO:

```
try {           
    $dbh = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=dbname',
    'root',
    'root',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Secondly, make sure that all your files (PHP files, HTML templates) are saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Thirdly, if all that fails, try playing with the iconv() function a bit more:

```
echo iconv("Latin1_General_CI_AS","utf-8",$row[0]);
echo iconv("Arabic_CI_AS","utf-8",$row[0]);
```

And so on.

Comment: SET NAMES 'utf8' is mysql statement while the question is about Microsoft SQL server 2005.
however, thank you for your attention and help.
my pages are saves as UTF-8
and echo iconv("Latin1_General_CI_AS","utf-8",$row[0]);
echo iconv("Arabic_CI_AS","utf-8",$row[0]); 
both of them prints nothing :(

Comment: Well, I haven't worked with MSSQL yet but isn't there some equivalent to SET NAMES?

Comment: unfortunately i dont know any equivalent in SQL server.
the problem is that the standard output encoding of sql server is unicode, but when i convert it to utf-8 it becomes Chinese!!!
however, if i got a solution, i will post it here for sure
Thanks